# Handling strategies with "complex" conditions without 'switch'/'if' statements

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, strategy-pattern

I am working on an application that will shortly be used for provisioning. The situation is not really complicated. The application manages groups that have access to services. Depending of the services the group has access, different business rules are applied.

The first idea (simple and stupid) would be to have a big if/else or switch/case that will cover all the cases. Here is how it could look like in pseudocode :

```
if (serviceA OR serviceB) {
    doActionA();
}
if(serviceA AND serviceC) {
    doActionA();
    doActionB();
}
if(serviceB AND serviceC) {
    doActionA();
    doActionC();
}
if(serviceA AND serviceB AND serviceC) {
    doActionA();
    doActionB();
    doActionC();
}
if(serviceD) {
    doActionD();
}
```

It is not very convenient because if add a new service, I would need to update this statement (that could be hundreds/thousands of lines long ! ).

After realizing that, I made my researches about which design pattern could help me solve this problem. The one that looks like could help me would be the Strategy pattern. Again, it doesn't change anything (or I don't understand it) and the code would look like this :

```
if (serviceA OR serviceB) {
    setStrategy(new StrategyA);
}
if(serviceA AND serviceC) {
    setStrategy(new StrategyB);
}
if(serviceB AND serviceC) {
    setStrategy(new StrategyC);
}
if(serviceA AND serviceB AND serviceC) {
    setStrategy(new StrategyD);
}
if(serviceD) {
    setStrategy(new StrategyE);
}

strategy.run();
```

In a way, this is even worse because I can only have one strategy, and notice how the serviceD does not have business rules related to others (it just have an action for itself). Then again, maybe i didn't understood the pattern.

Do you have any idea how I can handle such situation in the most elegant way ? I know that in the future I will have new services so I don't want to make a mistake now.
I hope I don't need to write a strategy for every combination (7 strategies for 3 services, 14 strategies for 4 services, it goes fast !)

Thank you by advance for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without making things unnecessary complicated with business rules and all that zoo, I'd just define predicate-strategy pairs.

For a predicate you'll need some kind of `Context` which would allow to check for `context.isServiceA()` etc.

For the strategy you'll probably also need some kind of `ExecutionContext` (maybe not if your strategies are self-contained).

So a `Predicate<Context>` would be a check if a strategy is applicable and `Consumer<ExecutionContext>` would be the strategy. Then you just need some kind of collection of `Predicate<Context>`/`Consumer<ExecutionContext>` pairs. If you don't want to write any additional classes, just use `LinkedHashMap`. Something like:

```
Map<Predicate<Context>, Consumer<ExecutionContext> rules = new LinkedHashMap<>();

rules.put(ctx -> ctx.isServiceA() || ctx.isServiceB(), new StrategyA());
rules.put(ctx -> ctx.isServiceA() && ctx.isServiceC(), new StrategyB());
```

And so on.

For syntactic sugar you may define things like `ctx -> ctx.isServiceA()` as constants and then

```
rules.put(SERVICE_A.or(SERVICE_B), new StrategyA());
```

During evaluation you just iterate over entries and the execute the first suitable strategy. Something like:

```
rules
.entrySet()
.filter(entry -> entry.getKey().test(context))
.findFirst()
.map(Entry::getValue)
.ifPresent(strategy -> strategy.accept(executionContext));
```

Another idea is to make strategies themselves decide if they are applicable or not. So a strategy will have a `test` method (or a predicate) and `apply` method. Then you'll just look for the applicable strategy to execute. I often did this in combination with Spring bean autodiscovery. Some central bean collects all implementations of some strategy interface and then chooses the one which is applicable to some conditions/context.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Unfortunately I am not working with java but php. Still, I think I get what you meant. Basically you are proposing to write rules in some kind of configuration file, loop over my rules in my “main” then execute the rules that are OK, right ? With this solution, either I’ll need a rule for every situation possible (rule for every combination) which is not convenient, or I might call multiple time the same strategy (in my example, if I have serviceA and serviceB, it will do actionA twice).

Comment: I propose tohat a strategy also provides a predicate when it's applicable. How you code this is entirely up to you. No, you don't necessarily need a rule for every situation or duplicate invocation. Just like in code you posted you have some order, some priority in rules. Once you've found a best suitable rule you just call the strategy and return. You're not forced to iterate further on.

Comment: I get it. However I still have to use multiple strategies if I do not duplicate. If the group has the service A and D, I have 2 different actions to do (so 2 strategies). What bothers me is that I'll have strategies that do exactly the same actions but with different parameters and I probably can't create a generic enough interface for that and other strategies. My other (and last) question is that I have multiple actions that concerns the same external app. If I cut them in X strategies I'll have to call X time the same WS to get the information foreach strategy. Do you know I can prevent it?